# Custom property binding in [FromUri] object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I use DTO objects as the parameters of requests to my JSON REST webservice, which is being migrated from WCF.

To get the products with the `id=1` or the `id=3` I have been using this Uri:

```
http://example.com/products?ids=1,3
```

For simplicity, I want to use existent DTO classes as `[FromUri]` parameter of my controller methods. For instance:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("products")]
public IHttpActionResult GetProducts([FromUri] GetProductRequestParameters parameters)
{
    ...
}
```

And this is the DTO:

```
public class GetProductRequestParameters
{
    public IEnumerable<int> Ids { get; set; }

    public int FamilyId { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that model binder expects something like `?Ids=1&Ids=3` instead of a "comma separated value" like `?Ids=1,3` for the property `IEnumerable<int>`

With the following code I've achieved to bind this kind of data if I use querystring parameters in the controller method instead of the DTO. I would prefer to use the later because DTOs can have lots of properties and I don't want to be filling in every parameter manually.

```
internal class CommaSeparatedIntegerCollectionModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult val = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (val == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string s = val.AttemptedValue;

        if (s == null || s.IndexOf(",", StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0)
        {
            bindingContext.Model = new int[] { };
        }

        var stringArray = s.Split(new[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var listInt = new List<int>(stringArray.Count());
        int valueInt;
        foreach (string valueString in stringArray)
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(valueString, out valueInt))
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Values are not numeric");
                return false;
            }

            listInt.Add(valueInt);
        }

        bindingContext.Model = listInt;

        return true;
    }
}
```

Is there some way I can instruct the model binder how to bind this kind of properties?

Comment: I tried creating a custom ValueProvider, but it only gets called if the default ASP.NET value provider doesn't find a value for the property name. Is there a way to favour my ValueProvider and have the ASP.NET on as fallback?